# File browser closing on Folder deletion

Tags: centos, gnome, display-settings

I am using CentOS

```
CentOS
Release 6.4(Final)
Kernel Linux 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64
GNOME 2.82.2
```

I have enabled "Always open in browser" option in the File management preferences. I have a script running that prints the log in a directory and if the script processing is successful script also deletes the logs and its dir. Logs and dir are not deleted if script processing fails.

Now when I have opened log directory and script processes successfully (dir is deleted ) whole browser is closed (along with all tabs it have!) rather than falling back to its parent directory(expected behavior).

Is there any setting that will prevent the file browser from  closing and make it fall back to its parent directory?

Comment: Why don't you provide the script?

Comment: How it has to do anything with the script? Imagine you are in a folder and you simple execute rm -rf targetDirectory. My problem is with gnome/nautilus setting not the script.